Steps to Resolve Serror Panic on ARMv8-A or How to Identify the Faulty Instruction?
I am familiar with kernel panic on x86 but recently encountered an Serror panic on ARMv8-A that needs resolution. Seeking guidance on the general steps to address Serror issues.
The code causing the panic is 0xbe000411. According to the ARMv8 manual, ISS: 0x411 AET is 001 Unrecoverable error (UEU).
I am unable to identify the faulty instruction. The dmesg points to tcp_set_state+0x4/0x1e8, indicating a simple mov instruction at 0xffffce3b1c776b2c <tcp_set_state+4>: mov x29, sp.
At this point, I am unsure how to proceed with troubleshooting as the panic log does not reflect the actual panic location, and the ARMv8 manual lacks information on how to determine the memory address causing the Serror.
The panic occurs across multiple machines, suggesting it may not be a hardware issue. All machines run the 64k page ARM version of kernel 5.4.210. The commonality lies in the occurrence during the execution of get_time within efi_runtime_service, interrupted by an IRQ, handled in the IRQ, leading to an Serror at tcp_set_state+0x4. For confidentiality reasons, BIOS and kernel versions have been omitted.
I noticed that the MM is switched to efi_mm when entering the EFI runtime service, so I suspect there might be an issue with the page table traversal of efi_mm. However, if this were the case, the problem should be very easy to reproduce. I tried stress-ng to stress all cores with TCP flows and continuously invoked hwclock to trigger efi_runtime_service, but after running for about half a day, I couldn't reproduce the issue.
            "[14020380.440647] SError Interrupt on CPU46, code 0xbe000411 -- SError",
            "[14020380.440648] CPU: 46 PID: 3999171 Comm: kworker/u256:5 Kdump: loaded Tainted: G           OE     5.4.210.xxx-64k-arm64 #64k",
            "[14020380.440648] Hardware name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, BIOS xxxxxxxxxx",
            "[14020380.440649] Workqueue: efi_rts_wq efi_call_rts",
            "[14020380.440651] pstate: 60400009 (nZCv daif +PAN -UAO)",
            "[14020380.440651] pc : tcp_set_state+0x4/0x1e8",
            "[14020380.440652] lr : tcp_fin+0xf8/0x1c0",
            "[14020380.440652] sp : ffff8000105cf6e0",
            "[14020380.440653] x29: ffff8000105cf760 x28: ffffa4e9cdf192c0 ",
            "[14020380.440654] x27: ffff40861a80b800 x26: ffff44831e5757a8 ",
            "[14020380.440655] x25: ffff445be3adc380 x24: 0000000000000020 ",
            "[14020380.440656] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffff44831e5757a8 ",
            "[14020380.440656] x21: ffffa4e9cd3f62f8 x20: ffff44831e575780 ",
            "[14020380.440657] x19: ffff445be3adc380 x18: 0000000000000000 ",
            "[14020380.440658] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: ffffa4e9ccfa1fa8 ",
            "[14020380.440659] x15: 00000000000000f4 x14: ccccccccccccce3c ",
            "[14020380.440660] x13: ffffffff00000000 x12: 0000000000000002 ",
            "[14020380.440661] x11: 0000000000000000 x10: 00000000000000a8 ",
            "[14020380.440662] x9 : 0000000000000004 x8 : ffff78860b5e7a00 ",
            "[14020380.440662] x7 : 0000000000000001 x6 : 00013eca54043561 ",
            "[14020380.440663] x5 : 000000000001bc00 x4 : 000000000000001b ",
            "[14020380.440664] x3 : 0000000000000302 x2 : 0000000000000001 ",
            "[14020380.440665] x1 : 0000000000000008 x0 : ffff445be3adc380 ",
            "[14020380.440666] Kernel panic - not syncing: Asynchronous SError Interrupt",
            "[14020380.440667] CPU: 46 PID: 3999171 Comm: kworker/u256:5 Kdump: loaded Tainted: G           OE     5.4.210.xxx-64k-arm64 #64k",
            "[14020380.440668] Hardware name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, BIOS xxxxxxxxxx",
            "[14020380.440668] Workqueue: efi_rts_wq efi_call_rts",
            "[14020380.440669] Call trace:",
            "[14020380.440669]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1f0",
            "[14020380.440670]  show_stack+0x24/0x30",
            "[14020380.440671]  dump_stack+0xbc/0x114",
            "[14020380.440671]  panic+0x158/0x36c",
            "[14020380.440672]  nmi_panic+0x68/0xa0",
            "[14020380.440672]  arm64_serror_panic+0x84/0x90",
            "[14020380.440672]  do_serror+0x84/0x128",
            "[14020380.440673]  el1_error+0x8c/0x108",
            "[14020380.440674]  tcp_set_state+0x4/0x1e8",
            "[14020380.440674]  tcp_data_queue+0x610/0xb90",
            "[14020380.440674]  tcp_rcv_established+0x1a8/0x558",
            "[14020380.440675]  tcp_v6_do_rcv+0xc0/0x490",
            "[14020380.440676]  tcp_v6_rcv+0xcd0/0xda8",
            "[14020380.440676]  ip6_protocol_deliver_rcu+0xf0/0x538",
            "[14020380.440676]  ip6_input_finish+0x30/0x40",
            "[14020380.440677]  ip6_input+0xb4/0xc0",
            "[14020380.440677]  ip6_sublist_rcv_finish+0x64/0x88",
            "[14020380.440678]  ip6_sublist_rcv+0x1f4/0x278",
            "[14020380.440678]  ipv6_list_rcv+0x130/0x160",
            "[14020380.440679]  __netif_receive_skb_list_core+0x158/0x270",
            "[14020380.440680]  netif_receive_skb_list_internal+0x1a8/0x2d8",
            "[14020380.440680]  gro_normal_list.part.151+0x24/0x40",
            "[14020380.440681]  napi_complete_done+0x118/0x1d0",
            "[14020380.440681]  mlx5e_napi_poll+0x25c/0x688 [mlx5_core]",
            "[14020380.440682]  net_rx_action+0x184/0x478",
            "[14020380.440682]  __do_softirq+0x128/0x34c",
            "[14020380.440683]  irq_exit+0xa4/0xc0",
            "[14020380.440684]  __handle_domain_irq+0x70/0xc0",
            "[14020380.440684]  gic_handle_irq+0xec/0x288",
            "[14020380.440684]  el1_irq+0xcc/0x180",
            "[14020380.440685]  0x2b263354",
            "[14020380.440686]  0x2b26c150",
            "[14020380.440686]  0x2b26c35c",
            "[14020380.440686]  0x2b26c79c",
            "[14020380.440687]  0x2b265184",
            "[14020380.440687]  0x2b265390",
            "[14020380.440687]  0x2b264334",
            "[14020380.440687]  0x2b260c1c",
            "[14020380.440688]  __efi_rt_asm_wrapper+0x28/0x44",
            "[14020380.440688]  efi_call_rts+0x88/0x458",
            "[14020380.440688]  process_one_work+0x1b4/0x410",
            "[14020380.440688]  worker_thread+0x150/0x528",
            "[14020380.440688]  kthread+0x124/0x128",
            "[14020380.440689]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x1c",


In my experience, SError exceptions are typically caused by cacheline writebacks to things that either don't like being written to, or don't like cacheline-sized writes. In those cases, the cacheline in question may have been modified by many instructions, possibly running on different CPUs that share said cache, so the information on which code address caused the writeback will have been lost by then. On the other hand, the faulting data address has to be known to hardware, but if it is exposed to software, then that is via implementation-defined means.

Thank you for your response. So, it may involve reading and writing to user-space addresses in the softirq handler, at a point when the MM has switched to efi_mm. When the cacheline writeback occurs, it writes to the efi runtime service code address corresponding to efi_mm, which cannot be written to, triggering the Serror. I will go through the entire ipv6_rcv process to see if there are any operations involving reading and writing to user-space addresses.
